# Adding children to PrimeNg TreeTable programmatically

Tags: angular, primeng, treetable

I'd like to add childNodes to a TreeTable programmatically. There's no problem adding the parent-nodes like:

```
var parentNode: TreeNode = { data: {
        'col1': 'aaa',
        'col2': 'aaa',
      }};

this.treeTableModel.push(parentNode);
```

But when I'm trying to do:

```
parentNode.children.push(childNode);
```

Children is undefined?

What's the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, you can look at `TreeNode` api here: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/bb1792eac98c7beb9d18ff68bed99408ad650108/components/common/api.ts

second, you initialized `parentNode` like this

```
var parentNode: TreeNode = { data: {
        'col1': 'aaa',
        'col2': 'aaa',
      }};
```

`parentNode` has no property `children` at this point. You'll have to add it. `children` is a `TreeNode` array: `TreeNode[]` so what you can do is:

```
var parentNode: TreeNode =
       { 
        data: {
          'col1': 'aaa',
          'col2': 'aaa',
         },
         children:[];
       };
```

now that `children` is initialized as an empty array, you can `push` to it:

`this.treeTableModel.push(parentNode);`

Comment: But how can you push to the array of selected nodes? [(selection)]="selectedNodes". You cant initialize it again, and it doesn't have children

Answer (score 3):

**You'll need to add empty children to parent and then add (push) data to children**

```
var parentNode: TreeNode = { 
    data: {
        'col1': 'aaa',
        'col2': 'aaa',
      },
    children: [{data: {}}]
    };

this.treeTableModel.push(parentNode);
```

**Add (push) data to children**

On `onNodeExpand` function

```
onNodeExpand(e: event) {
    e['node']['children'] = childData;
    this.treeTableModel = [...this.treeTableModel];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After you push to the TreeNode as parent or parent with child/ren, per Ahmed's post, you then refresh it but doing this.

this.treeTableModel = [...this.treeTableModel];

The TreeTable data reflects what you just pushed into the TreeNode.